# DevExpress ComboBoxEdit - Binding only returns path instead of value

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I have a DevXpress ComboBoxEdit and have the XML code as follows

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Grid.Row="1" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,27,0,0" 
                 Name="cbExcelReports" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="664"
                 IsTextEditable="False"
                 DisplayMember="DisplayName"
                 Style="{StaticResource ValidationStyle}" Focusable="True"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding AllExcelReports}" SelectedItem="{Binding ReportType, Mode=OneWayToSource, Path=ReportType}"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

This binding works fine for retrieving the items to be placed in the drop down list and the user can select one and it'll appear in the combobox when selected.

I only require the text of the selected item from the combobox, I use this string property in the binding

```
 private string _ReportType;

public string ReportType
     {
         get { return this._ReportType; }
         set
         {
             this._ReportType = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged("ReportType");
         }
     }
```

When I select an item in the combobox I only get the path (if that's the correct term?) of the object, instead of the actual text within chosen. (shown in a messagebox below)

[image]

I've a feeling that my XML code is wrong, but I can't put my finger on what it is, doe's anyone have an answer that could push me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an answer here as I used different approach to using ObservableCollections. I ended up using a Dictionary and binding the dictionary to the combobox, which works fine. Only the value selected was of any importance so thats fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

For each combobox item you have to define the text that is to appear when this item is selected with TextSearch.Text:

```
      <ComboBoxItem TextSearch.Text="this is text of this item">
```

Comment: Great, I'll get back to you when I get back on the computer tomorrow

Comment: despite adding this I'm still not getting the value, just Models.ViewModel as before. Thanks for the idea however

Comment: I suppose Textsearch.Text does not work when the itemssource is bound. It does work for ComboBoxItems which are explicitly listed in xaml. Sorry.